# How do I enable Developer Mode for Outlook 2010 by only using the registry?

Tags: outlook, registry

I've researched this a bit and came up dry.  I've checked HKCU/Software/Microsoft but Office is not listed.  Our company uses Office 2010 Pro Plus.  Under HKLM, I can see Office 14.0 but Outlook/Options keys are not there.  I've created the DeveloperTools 32bit DWORD and set the value to 1 under HKLM and HKCU with the following paths, but neither worked:

HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Office/14.0/Outlook/Options/DeveloperTools = 1

HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Office/14.0/Outlook/Options/DeveloperTools = 1

I am trying to use the registry because I need to modify many machines within our domain and don't want to send an email out asking everyone to "check the box" so-to-speak.  Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Did you restart Outlook after modifying the key?

Comment: I did. I closed and reopened it to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a wrong key - at least under Outlook 2013 the key is

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\General]
"ReportAddinCustomUIErrors"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I modified that key to 14.0 instead and restarted outlook.  The option is still not present.  Thanks for the assist though.

Comment: Try to use a utility like RegFromApp (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) to figure out what changes when the option is turned on and off.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I won't be able to use that at work but I'll test on my home machine with the same software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) utility for monitoring the windows registry activity.

Also check out whether the Click2Run edition of Outlook is installed on the machine. See [Verify Whether Outlook Is a Click-to-Run Application on a Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.